# Ruby on Rails multiple associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, activeadmin

I try to make an application where a user (call client) put a document and make it corrected by another user (call corrector).

I have a classic User table, I have a Document Table and Correction table
When the client decide to send to a corrector his file, it will duplicate the Document into the corrector account.

In my User model I have:

```
has_many :documents
has_many :cclient,    :class_name => 'Correction', :foreign_key => 'client_id'
has_many :ccorector,  :class_name => 'Correction', :foreign_key => 'corrector_id'
```

In my Document model I have:

```
belongs_to :user
has_one  :cclient,    :class_name => 'Correction', :foreign_key => 'client_document_id'
has_one  :ccorrector, :class_name => 'Correction', :foreign_key => 'corrector_document_id'
```

Finaly in my Correction model I have:

```
belongs_to :client,             :class_name => 'User',  :foreign_key => "client_id"
belongs_to :corrector,          :class_name => 'User',  :foreign_key => "corrector_id"
belongs_to :client_document,    :class_name => 'Document', :foreign_key => "client_document_id"
belongs_to :corrector_document, :class_name => 'Document', :foreign_key => "corrector_document_id"
```

My problem is when i try to reach the index page of Correction in ActiveAdmin I see in my log:

```
User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
Document Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "documents".* FROM "documents" 
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "documents".* FROM "documents"
```

And i'm pretty sure that the reason why in production i reach a timeout.

Where am I wrong ?

EDIT: Here my correction.rb (in active admin)

```
#encoding: utf-8
ActiveAdmin.register Correction do
  config.per_page = 10
  index do
    column :id
    default_actions
  end


  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Correction" do
      f.input :client_id
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

Comment: you should post the code for your `corrections#index` action. Otherwise we cannot tell you why this is happening you could be calling `User.all` and `Document.all` which would create these queries.

Comment: Edited. I reduced it to the minimum and i still got the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **`User`** model  and **`Document`** model seems weird to me.Why you are having preceding **`c`** in **`cclient`** and **`ccorector`**? and you **`mispelled`** the **`corector`(it should be corrector)**. And for **`has_many`** relation,you should be using **`plural form`** not **`singular form`**.

I guess your **`User`** model and **`Document`** model should look like this

```
#user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :documents
has_many :clients,    :class_name => 'Correction', :foreign_key => 'client_id'
has_many :correctors, :class_name => 'Correction', :foreign_key => 'corrector_id'

end

#document.rb
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user
has_one  :client,    :class_name => 'Correction', :foreign_key => 'client_document_id'
has_one  :corrector, :class_name => 'Correction', :foreign_key => 'corrector_document_id'

end
```

Comment: Ty. I removed all the belongs_to in my Correction model, it solves the problem.

Comment: @GeorgesLeYeti Glad it worked! Please accept my answer if it seems helpful :)